# Responsive three column layout with fixed header, footer and side panels

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

The below code is the closet I was able to achieve and exactly how I need it to function, the only **problem** with this approach is that because the fixed div is layered on top of the main div, it renders the main container not clickable.

This is how I need the layout to function:

1. There should be three columns, the outer two columns (sidepanels, left and right) are fixed.
2. The header and footer are also fixed and take up the max width of the
   center "main" column (and are positioned in the center like the center "main" column).
3. On window resize, only the width of the center column (along with the
   header and footer) is auto adjusted while the side columns stay the same
   width (squeezing the center column).

I am trying to avoid the use of flexbox for browser compatibility.

```css
body {
  background: #333;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 1240px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: inherit;
}

.main {
  background: #444;
  position: relative;
  padding: 70px 10px;
  height: 1000px;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 280px;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 220px;
}

.header,
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  background: #555;
  height: 60px;
  left: 220px;
  right: 220px;
}

.header {
  top: 0;
}

.footer {
  bottom: 0;
}

.left,
.right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 220px;
  background: #666;
  height: 100%;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="header">header</div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  main
</div>
```

Comment: Don't put all the elements into the same fixed div - make them fixed individually. Or change the z-index of main. But either way, I still think you are better to use flexbox - it has [at least partial support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) in all the major currently-used browsers - even IE10 and IE11 which are no longer supported!

Comment: I have tried placing them separately but I always end up with a problem such as the header and footer do not resize correctly, or are wider than the main container. Would you be able to guide me to a flexbox solution that functions correctly?

Comment: Not using *flexbox* in this case would be a mistake, as your requirements will work perfectly with *flexbox* in any major browser (given a few quirks you might need to adress, check @FluffyKitten 's link). Check these links on Codepen: [MDN Holy Grail Flexbox Layout](https://codepen.io/fskirschbaum/pen/LVPeJb) or my own Pen (resembles your layout): [Easy Responsive Typography (CSS only)](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/57ace267758f76d4c2abfd4f022b9f4f).

Comment: I cannot get the fixed header and footer to respect the width of the wrapper in my flexbox attempt: http://codepen.io/artydnyc/pen/wvGJLmd